# assign a variable with more than one capital letter

Tags: python, spyder

I think that my question is very stupid. I'm using windows / Python 3.7 / spyder (just updated)
If I write in the terminal `g=3` and press enter, I get a variable named g in the variable explorer, if I say `GA=3`, nothing appears in the variable explorer but if I write `GA` in the terminal the variable is there. I have no idea what is happening here. It only happens when the variable name has more than one capital letter.

Comment: Probably, capital letter variables more than one characters are treated as constants. If you type A=3, it shows. However, AA=3, it does not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their github [issues](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/290)

> For example entering the following at the commandline: TESTVAR = 2
> will not show up in the workspace, although testvar = 2 will show up.

> That's because there is an option to hide this kind of variable which
> should be (according to Python official guidelines) a global variable
> in an imported module (imported with the non-recommended statement
> "from foobar import *". Anyway to show these variables, just tick the
> option "show upper case [something]" (context menu)

So, there in an options icon in the vertical bar at the right of the Variables explorer which allows you to enable/disable the uppercase variables.

Note: "Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL", according to PEP-8. And it is probably this very convention that Spyder follows that caused the behaviour you observed.